# Prevent Overlapping Features in QGIS from Being Faded

Tags: qgis, layers, transparency-opacity

I have multiple layers in QGIS that I've set as transparent so I can see their respective features. However, I would like one layer (showing proportionally sized points) to NOT fade when it overlaps with a block group layer.
In other words I'd like to move my points on top and have **UN**faded color fills, (aka "Move to Front" as one does with MS products), but otherwise retain the visibility of the underlying block group layer everywhere else.

Comment: Have you an image of the problem as you are seeing it currently please? In QGIS you can organise the layers  so that points are on top in the layers pane and just set their style differently. Guessing that isn't what your after though!

Comment: Jono,That worked!  Thank you!  I simply dragged the points layer above the block-group layer and my points are not faded/transparent.Thanks!

Comment: @JonoPatterson - You should post your comment as an answer is it solved Ben's problem :)

Comment: Ok I will! Wasn't sure if to make a comment an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS you can organise the layers so that points are on top in the layers pane and just set their style differently. See image:

[image: Ordering layers]